# phpinfo.php doesn't show anyoutput apache2

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

I am a web developer and I've just switched from windows 10 to ubuntu 18.04. I've tried unstalling and reinstalling it again and alomst all the solutions that's been provided by fellow developers on ask.ubuntu, ubuntu forums, stackoverflow etc.

i don't understand what seems to be the problem. I've installed php, openssh.server and apache. I made phpinfo.php in /var/www/html and when i'm trying to run it on localhost it says "unable to connect". I've shared the output for sudo service apache2 start[image]

Comment: Did you install all of these using `apt` or some other method?

Comment: Apache is not running. Maybe you are using php-fpm? This is depending on running apache2. Check your apache2 configuration.

Comment: Yes, i installed all of these using apt

Comment: yes, I have installed php-fpm. What should i change in .conf? @MarkusZeller

Comment: Have a look in the apache error log (default in /var/log/apache2/error.log) and try to figure out what's wrong starting the service.

Comment: @MarkusZeller It turned out to be omitted archives in apt file. As some of them were unavailable in my region. And then the missing apachectl in /user/sbin, i had to run `sudo apt install --reinstall apache2 apache-bin`. And its working perfectly now. ;)